# Overall SVG opacity/transparency

Tags: html, svg

What is the best way to control an SVG's opacity/transparency? I saw attributes like fill-opacity, but I do not want to make it specific for "fill". Instead I would like to define a overall transparency for the whole SVG image. I am looking for a way to do this within the SVG and not from outside.
The situation is that you have one SVG inside another.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>
....
  <image ... xlink:href="half-transparent.svg" />
....
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `opacity` property. You can make it apply to the whole svg if you want, details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#OpacityProperty).